# Laravel route redirect without closure for route cache

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I have this code on my `routes.php` file that do a redirect. Though the problem is that whenever I ran `php artisan route:cache` command, it gives me an error of `Unable to prepare route [article/{params}] for serialization. Uses Closure.`

I know this has something to do with routes not allowing it to be cached if it have a closure. But how could I make a workaround for this redirect?

```
Route::get('article/{params}', function($params) {
    return Redirect::to($params, 301);
});
```

Comment: I believe you should be able to move your return to a controller and it will bypass this issue.

Comment: are you running the command with in or outside the vm, try with in the vm

Comment: @simonDavies I'm running the command outside vm. I'm not using any vm for this. Just running xampp on my local.

Comment: as @DavidNguyen said that use a controller as it currently not able to use route cache if using closures i beleive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Route caching does not work with Closure based routes. To use route caching, you must convert any Closure routes to use controller classes.

```
Route::get('article/{params}', 'HelperController@redirect');
```

in your controller you can have your redirect function like below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HelperController extends Controller
{
  public function redirect($params)
  {
    return Redirect::to($params, 301);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would someone possibly know how to do this scenario wherein it will pass arguments to the controller? `Route::get('articles/{params}', function($params) {
    return Redirect::to('articles/' . $params . '/edit', 301);
});` The `articles/` should be an argument that could be pass on to the controller so that I can just have one(1) controller that does redirect. This is because I have several of this lines that just do the same functionality and I do not want to create specific controllers for each redirect. It must be a dynamic controller that can accept parameters.

Answer (score 7):

Since `Laravel 5.5` you can use:

`Route::redirect('/here', '/there', 301);`

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#basic-routing) under **Redirect Routes**.

Comment: SO much better!

Answer (score 4):

It appears that caching routes now also works with Closures.

The warning in the docs is also gone from Laravel 7:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#route-caching
to Laravel 8:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching

Tested it also in a project and it does not complain.